# Android .sswan profile to ipsec.conf

Tags: vpn, ipsec, strongswan, watchguard

I have a .sswan profile with an embedded cert and username/password from a server admin. It connects to a Watchguard VPN without any issues. I was told by the server admin I can connect with my ubuntu server "natively". I haven't been able to find that true but in my research I found that the linux strongswan application can connect. What is the correct parameters to make the connection succeed?

Im using Linux strongSwan U5.9.5/K5.19.0-1025-aws

The connection is failing. Errors I'm getting:`'username_from_admin' not confirmed by certificate`
and `no private key found for 'O=WatchGuard_Technologies, OU=Fireware, CN=Fireware IKE (SN xxx 2023-03-14 13:57:23 UTC) CA'`

I have attached my logs and connection parameters below.

[image: .sswan file]

**SYSLOG:**

```
ipsec[421754]: 00[NET] using forecast interface ens5
ipsec[421754]: 00[CFG] joining forecast multicast groups: 224.0.0.1,224.0.0.22,224.0.0.251,224.0.0.252,239.255.255.250
ipsec[421754]: 00[CFG] loading ca certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/cacerts'
ipsec[421754]: 00[CFG] loading aa certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/aacerts'
ipsec[421754]: 00[CFG] loading ocsp signer certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/ocspcerts'
ipsec[421754]: 00[CFG] loading attribute certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/acerts'
ipsec[421754]: 00[CFG] loading crls from '/etc/ipsec.d/crls'
ipsec[421754]: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
ipsec[421754]: 00[CFG]   loaded EAP secret for username_from_admin
ipsec[421754]: 00[CFG] loaded 0 RADIUS server configurations
ipsec[421754]: 00[CFG] HA config misses local/remote address
ipsec[421754]: 00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac gcm drbg attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark forecast farp stroke updown eap-identity eap-aka eap-md5 eap-gtc eap-mschapv2 eap-dynamic eap-radius eap-tls eap-ttls eap-peap eap-tnc xauth-generic xauth-eap xauth-pam tnc-tnccs dhcp lookip error-notify certexpire led addrblock unity counters
ipsec[421754]: 00[LIB] dropped capabilities, running as uid 0, gid 0
ipsec[421754]: 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads
ipsec[421750]: charon (421754) started after 60 ms
ipsec[421754]: 05[CFG] received stroke: add connection 'XYZ-IKEv2-VPN'
ipsec[421754]: 05[KNL] 8.x.x.x is not a local address or the interface is down
ipsec[421754]: 05[CFG]   loaded certificate "O=WatchGuard_Technologies, OU=Fireware, CN=Fireware IKE (SN XYZ 2023-03-14 13:57:23 UTC) CA" from '/etc/ipsec.d/certs/rootca.pem'
ipsec[421754]: 05[CFG]   id 'username_from_admin' not confirmed by certificate, defaulting to 'O=WatchGuard_Technologies, OU=Fireware, CN=Fireware IKE (SN XYZ 2023-03-14 13:57:23 UTC) CA'
ipsec[421754]: 05[CFG] added configuration 'XYZ-IKEv2-VPN'
```

**RESULT OF running:** `sudo ipsec up XYZ-IKEv2-VPN COMMAND`

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxx:/$ sudo systemctl restart strongswan-starter
ubuntu@ip-xxxx:/$ sudo ipsec up XYZ-IKEv2-VPN
initiating IKE_SA XYZ-IKEv2-VPN[1] to 8.x.x.x
generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
sending packet: from 172.31.x.x[500] to 8.x.x.x[500] (1164 bytes)
received packet: from 8.x.x.x[500] to 172.31.x.x[500] (496 bytes)
parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) V ]
received unknown vendor ID: bf:c2:2e:98:56:ba:99:36:11:c1:1e:48:a6:d2:08:07:a9:5b:ed:b3:93:02:6a:49:e6:0f:ac:32:7b:b9:60:1b:56:6b:34:39:4d:54:49:75:4f:53:34:79:49:45:4a:4f:50:54:59:33:4e:54:67:78:4e:77:3d:3d
selected proposal: IKE:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/MODP_2048
local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
sending cert request for "O=WatchGuard_Technologies, OU=Fireware, CN=Fireware IKE (SN xxx 2023-03-14 13:57:23 UTC) CA"
no private key found for 'O=WatchGuard_Technologies, OU=Fireware, CN=Fireware IKE (SN xxx 2023-03-14 13:57:23 UTC) CA'
establishing connection 'XYZ-IKEv2-VPN' failed
```

**ipsec.conf:**

```
conn XYZ-IKEv2-VPN
     leftsourceip=%config
     auto=add
     ike=aes256gmac-prfsha256-modp2048
     esp=aes256gmac-modp2048
     keyexchange=ikev2
     right=8.x.x.x
     rightsubnet=172.30.x.x
     rightid=8.x.x.x
     leftid=username_from_admin
     leftcert=/etc/ipsec.d/certs/rootca.pem
```

**ipsec.secrets:**

```
username_from_admin : EAP "password_from_admin"
```

**cert file location:**
ipsec.d/certs/

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues I can see:

- `leftcert` is your own certificate, not the server's, which would be in `rightcert`, but...
- ...since that seems to be a CA certificate, you don't have to configure it in ipsec.conf, just move it to `/etc/ipsec.d/cacerts`
- Since the profile is set for client authentication via EAP and not a certificate, you also want to configure `leftauth=eap`